# How to move one eclipse project from git repository to another repository with history

Tags: git, eclipse, gitlab

Hello I have a problem with moving one eclipse project from one repository to other with history.

I need move eclipse project Adam with his history of commits, branches and tags (basically all history) from repository https://gitlab.company.cz/CO/ProjectsA.git which contains also eclipse projects Beta, Gama and Delta. I want move just project Adam to another repository https://gitlab.company.cz/CO/Archive.git which contain eclipse projects Omega and Xara.

**Now**:

Folders (Projects) in https://gitlab.company.cz/CO/ProjectsA.git

```
Adam
Beta
Gama
Delta
.gitingore
```

Folders (Projects) in https://gitlab.company.cz/CO/Archive.git

```
Omega
Xara
.gitingore
```

**Expected**:

Folders (Projects) in https://gitlab.company.cz/CO/ProjectsA.git

```
Beta
Gama
Delta
.gitingore
```

Folders (Projects) in https://gitlab.company.cz/CO/Archive.git

```
Adam                                                                                          
Omega
Xara
.gitingore
```

I found this code, but I don't believe it

```
git clone https://gitlab.company.cz/CO/ProjectsA
cd ProjectsA
git checkout --orphan temp_branch
git rm -rf .
git remote add new_repo https://gitlab.company.cz/CO/Archive
git fetch origin
git merge origin/Adam --allow-unrelated-histories
git push new_repo temp_branch:Adam
git rm -r Adam
git commit -m "Remove Adam"
git push origin master
```